# Is it possible to make this macro faster? Copy and paste when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with macro running too slow and I guess it is just because of lack of my knowledge.

I have a macro that is copying data from "database" and paste it to another sheet. Macro is taking the names from the list in Sheet1 and looks for matches in Sheet2. When the match is found is copying a specific cell.

Right now I have a macro for each person on the list so I have 5 the same macros doing the same thing so maybe that why it takes so much time.... (around 3min)

Is there any way to make it faster? below my code so far

```
Sub CopySalesMan1()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 25).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 12).Value Then

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Copy

    erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 25).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 6).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 21).Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow + 1, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False




End If

Next i

End Sub
```

And the macro calling for every salesman in the list

```
Sub All()

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L7").Value <> "" Then Call CopySalesMan2
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L8").Value <> "" Then Call CopySalesMan3
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L9").Value <> "" Then Call CopySalesMan4
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L10").Value <> "" Then Call CopySalesMan5


End Sub
```

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that describes the code's _purpose_ rather than your concerns about it. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226). Also see [ask] for examples of good Code Review question titles.

Comment: Hi! thanks for advice! I will keep that in mind when posting next question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
Sub CopySalesMan()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim XlWkSht As Worksheet, sVal As String, lRow As Long, i As Long, r As Long
Set XlWkSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = XlWkSht.Range("D" & XlWkSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 6 To 10
  If XlWkSht.Range("L" & i).Value <> "" Then
     sVal = XlWkSht.Range("L" & i).Value
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
      For r = 2 To .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("Y" & r).Value2 = sVal Then
          lRow = lRow + 1
          XlWkSht.Range("B" & lRow).Value = .Range("B" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("C" & lRow).Value = .Range("Y" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("D" & lRow).Value = .Range("C" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("E" & lRow).Value = .Range("D" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("F" & lRow).Value = .Range("E" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("G" & lRow).Value = .Range("F" & r).Value
          XlWkSht.Range("H" & lRow).Value = .Range("U" & r).Value
        End If
      Next r
    End With
  End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```